# Visual Studio 2019 how do I go from Diff window to editor of the same file

Tags: visual-studio-2019

If I click a changed file in the list of changes in Team Viewer. I see the diff window which shows me differences. In Visual Studio Code there is a button which you could click and you get to the file to edit it. How I can do same in Visual Studio 2019?
I really do not wanna through the Solution Explorer and look for it.

Answer (score 2):

Right click in the right pane of the diff window and select **View Code** from the context menu.

Comment: Sergey, I do not have it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ow2oXNuqjSBhPZlsejEUTN1jHru7_1Ez/view?usp=sharing

Comment: After some testing, I see View Code for a modified .cs file, but don't see for a modified .config file. So it is probably a file type limited feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can click the **Sync with active document** button on the Solution Explorer toolbar and it will select the opened in the diff editor file.

Comment: Sync with Active Document not always displayed